# Saving to another Model database, with current Form record ID - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, model-associations

I'm trying to get the text from a `text_area` field in a form to save to a database in a different Model with the current Model's ID.

Currently, this works but only will save integers. If I put text into the 'Notes' field, then its saves it as a '0'. I suspect this is working correctly but I'm missing a piece to my puzzle. This is because I only want the 'Ticket' to save the note_id because I will have multiple 'Notes' per 'Ticket.

How can I get the Note to save in the Note Model, with an ID, and associate that `note_id` with this specific ticket?

Form - **/app/views/tickets/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@ticket) do |f| %>
<% if @ticket.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@ticket.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ticket from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% @ticket.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.fields_for :notes do |u|%>
  <%= u.label :note %>
  <%= u.text_area :note, :size => "101x4", :placeholder => "Leave notes here." %>
<% end %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**Tickets_controller.rb**

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
# GET /tickets
# GET /tickets.json
def index
@tickets = Ticket.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @tickets }
end
end

# GET /tickets/1
# GET /tickets/1.json
def show
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @ticket }
end
end

# GET /tickets/new
# GET /tickets/new.json
def new
@ticket = Ticket.new
@ticket.notes.build

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @ticket }
end
end

# GET /tickets/1/edit
def edit
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /tickets
# POST /tickets.json
def create
@ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket])

respond_to do |format|
  if @ticket.save
    format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @ticket, status: :created, location: @ticket }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PUT /tickets/1
# PUT /tickets/1.json
def update
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @ticket.update_attributes(params[:ticket])
    format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /tickets/1
# DELETE /tickets/1.json
def destroy
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
@ticket.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to tickets_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
end
```

**Note.rb**

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :ticket
attr_accessible :note, :ticket_id
end
```

**Ticket.rb**

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :notes_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `note_id` is an `integer` type.

Use `nested models`:
[Refer this for Nested Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715293/creating-nested-models-rails-3-1)

**Model:**

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
  attr_accessible :note_id, :notes_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes
end
```

**View:**

```
<%= form_for(@ticket) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :notes do |u|%>
      <%= u.label :note %>
      <%= u.text_area :note %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks - I want it to save the note_id here, so that part is correct. But, I can't seem to figure out how to get the note to save in the Note Model database and associate the `note_id`, with the `ticket_id`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you have `note_id` in ticket model ?

Comment: @codeit You're right he doesn't need that in there. His Note model / row will have a `ticket_id` column.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. The reason I have `note_id` in the ticket model is because I want to have the possibility off adding multiple notes to a ticket. My logic is to create the Note and add the `ticket-id` to each noted created.  Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: @Devin You can technically do that, sure. Or you can append to the ticket's array of notes (the has_many behaves like an array). Simply do `my_existing_ticket.notes << my_new_note_object`, followed by `my_existing_ticket.save`

Comment: @codeit Same with Teeg's response below. It doesn't appear to save the text in the Notes field though. When I go back to edit the ticket, the notes field is empty.

Comment: What do you have in `edit` and `update` action of your controller? You mean it is not saving at all?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be saving at all. I didn't change the `edit` or `update` actions in my Tickest_controller. All other fields save though. Do I need to add something?

Comment: Will the submit button on submit for both the main and nested form?

Comment: @Devin Yes, it is considered one huge atomic unit, so the submit button will submit all the data for both the parent and the nested form. When, in your `create` function for example, you do Ticket.new(params[:ticket]), the nested Note object(s) will be simultaneously created.

Comment: @codeit - I copied and pasted your updated code, unfortunately it still doesn't seem to be saving.  I feel like we're so close!

Comment: @Devin can you post your view and controller code? It will be easy to help.

Comment: @Devin Try adding `@ticket.notes.build` in `new` action of controller.

Comment: "ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in TicketsController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: notes_attributes"

Comment: Add `attr_accessible :notes_attributes` in ticket model

Comment: Dude. You are freaking awesome! That worked!! Thank you so much. Especially for the continued support.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a nested association, with `Ticket` as the "parent". The association is governed by the link from `note_id` in the `Note` model to the `id` (primary key) of the `Ticket`. What you're presently doing right now is manually manipulating that numeric association. Rails, knowing that the `note_id` column is supposed to be an integer, is taking the text you're trying to insert and turning it in to a number (zero in this case). You've probably got a bunch of orphaned rows right now because of this.

Ultimately, in order to accomplish what you're trying to do, your form will need to provide fields for that associated model. One way you can handle this is by using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your `Ticket` model. Like so:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :notes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes
end
```

And in your form, you can easily create a nested form like so:

```
<%= form_for(@ticket) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
        <%= f.fields_for :notes do |f_notes|%>
            <%= f_notes.label :note %><br />
            <%= f_notes.text_area :note, :size => "101x4", :placeholder => "Please leave notes here."%>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Edit** Almost forgot: Check out this [Railscast from Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast) dealing with Nested Attributes

**Edit 2** As codeit pointed out, you don't need the `attr_accessible :note_id` in Ticket. Since you've indicated that a `Ticket` has many `Notes`, and that `Note` belongs to `Ticket`, the foreign key column will appear in the `Note` model as `ticket_id`, which you already have. Having note_id in the ticket model is useless, and also nonsensical since has_many describes a plural relationship (which can't be expressed with a single column).

Comment: This definitely makes sense, thanks for being so thorough. It doesn't appear to save the text in the Notes field though. When I go back to edit the ticket, the notes field is empty.

Comment: @Devin So it doesn't appear on the form? Hmm, is the note field for that particular ticket populated in the database at least?

Comment: Thanks for continued support. The field is indeed there, just empty (with placeholder text). When in a list view of the data in my Notes Model, nothing appears there either.

Comment: It should be `f.fields_for`