# Load data from one model into a form, and save to another model, using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have three controllers: Users, Courses, and SavedCourses and corresponding models: User, Course, and SavedCourse
The data "flow" is:

1. Courses are added to the courses table by a sponsor; each course has
       14 fields.
2. A student requests a course by submitting a form with
       4 fields - class date, course id, sponsor name, and his / her id. 
       The input form is in the Views / Users folder and points to the
       courses table: form_for(@course).  The request is saved and added to
       the courses table by the Courses controller.
3. The incomplete record is matched to complete courses and the 'match' is parsed for
   each field's information.  That happens in the Courses controller.
4. The information is passed to a partial (confirmation form) in a
   page in the Views / Users folder for confirmation and 'save' as a
   record in the saved_courses table.

Between points "3" and "4" something breaks.  I suspect my actions are in the wrong controller and / or I'm labeling my fields incorrectly.  I'd appreciate another set of eyes on this.  Here's the code:

In the Courses controller
Get partial record's information - The information submitted by the student

```
Def new
  new_record = Course.where ... Some fields are null
  row = new_record.first

  active_date = row.class_date
  active_course = row.course_id
  active_sponsor = row.sponsor_name
```

Match on class_date, course_id, and sponsor_name

```
  abc = Course.where .... This works (using foregoing variables as inputs)
```

Getting values for use in the confirmation form
Still in the Courses controller and new method

```
  @saved_course = SavedCourse.new
  @saved_course.class_date = abc.class_date ... etc. for the remaining fields
  ... etc. for the remaining fields
```

Everything to this point works in the rails console.
I tried placing the "Def new" code in the SavedCourses controller and it didn't work
The values should be passed to a partial (a confirmation form) that's part of a page in the Views / Users folder:

```
  <%= form_for(@saved_course) do |f| %>
    <div>
    <li style="list-style-type: none; float: left;">
    <%= f.label :class_date %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :class_date, :value => @saved_course.class_date, autofocus: true %>
    </li>
    </div>
```

... followed by more fields

Unfortunately, the form renders with blank / empty fields rather than fields with the @saved_course information.  I, incidentally, tried it with and without autofocus.  I'd like to enable editing by the student, so I left the fields as text-area with autofocus.

There are no errors being reported by the server, console.log, or rails console.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around some more and re-phrasing my question, I discovered nesting.  Here's a link to a previous Stackoverflow answer Creating nested models: [Creating nested models - Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715293/creating-nested-models-rails-3-1)  Also, look at Ryan Bates Railscasts #196 and #197, Nested Model Form: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?  (The link is for the first one, #196.)